# countable dense subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, analysis

Let $I$ be some uncountable index set. For $\iota\in I$ and $j\in\mathbb N$ let $A_{\iota,j}\subseteq\mathbb R^d.$ Then there exists a countable dense subset in $A:=\overline{\bigcup_{\iota\in I}\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb N}A_{\iota,j}},$ since it is a subset of $\mathbb R^d$. But what I want to show is that there exist countably many $i_k\in I,$ $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $A=\overline{\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb N}A_{\iota_k,j}}.$ Is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course!  A basic fact about metric spaces is that separable metric spaces are *hereditarily separable* (every subspace is separable).  But a topological fact is that the hereditary separability of a topological space $X$ is equivalent to the following condition:

> For any $Y \subseteq X$ there is a countable $B \subseteq Y$ with $\overline{B} = \overline{Y}$.

(If $X$ is hereditarily separable and $Y \subseteq X$, then there is a countable $B \subseteq Y$ such that $\mathrm{cl}_Y (B ) = Y$.  But as $\mathrm{cl}_Y ( B ) = \overline{B} \cap Y$ it easily follows that $\overline{B} = \overline{Y}$.)

So, setting $Y = \bigcup_\iota \bigcup_j A_{\iota,j}$, by hereditary separability there is a countable $B \subseteq Y$ such that $\overline{B} = \overline{Y}$, and now for each $x \in B$ pick an $\iota_x$ such that $x \in \bigcup_j A_{\iota_x,j}$.